# APDU command to get smart card uid

Tags: smartcard, uniqueidentifier, apdu

i am looking for APDU to find UID of contact less ISO 14443 smart card and how to use it to print in Linux terminal. Problem is that i found many people talking about it, but there is no solution. Can anyone help is this regard???
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789290/589259), it is likely that most readers do support the pass through to the card reader by now.

---

Nobody can help as the UID is specified in the ISO 14443 T=CL transport protocol while APDU's are specified in the ISO 7816 application layer protocol.

So you need access to a lower level API for your contactless reader. PCSC will not suffice (unless there has been a pass through implemented for the specific reader that returns the UID).

Comment: So, what could be the possible way to read UID of smart card while working with PCSC-Lite?

Comment: I would have a look at the underlying reader libraries. PCSC was initially made for contact readers anyway. Problem is that anything beyond PCSC is likely to be proprietary drivers.

Comment: Does `UID` is specific per every contact-less card in world? (i.e. isn't there two different cards with equal UID?) Is it fixed or it is a random number per session? Why we need it? Just for Anti-Collision mechanism?

Comment: As far as I know, it is only `7` byte, So we can have `2^56` contact-less cards with different AIDs, right?

Comment: @Abraham That's usually a static UID yes, there are also 4 byte random UID's that are. The initial bits specify what kind of UID it is. Note that 2^56 is a lot (16 digits at least), but those bits are not all part of the unique ID. **EDIT** wrote this down wrong way around, 7 bytes is usually non-random.

Answer (score 24):

"Get Data Command" is defined in PCSC 3 v2. If your driver is PCSC v2 compliant, you can get UID using it:

```
Class = 0xFF
INS = 0xCA
P1 = 0x00
P2 = 0x00
Le = 0x00 (return full length: ISO14443A single 4 bytes, double 7 bytes, triple 10 bytes, for ISO14443B 4 bytes PUPI, for 15693 8 bytes UID)
```

Returned value is:

```
Data+SW1SW2
```

Comment: A Linux command to read the UID using opensc: 
opensc-tool --send-apdu FF:CA:00:00:00 --wait

Comment: Thanks @nchokoev!
Solved my problem with pcsclite (node adaption)