# Read java card uid

Tags: uniqueidentifier, javacard, apdu

i am new to java card development.i need to know how to read uid in java card using apdu commands .i couldn't find a solution.i found only how to select the Application id( APDU format
0x00,0xA4,0x04,00) same way i need to detect the uid in java card.can anyone tell me how to do that..

Thanks
SSV

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13051167/27190.

Comment: @martijno +1 for that :P